# PEG.js: how to use prompt?

Tags: javascript, pegjs

I'm creating a C++ parser with PEG.js, and I need to be able to use `cin`. With the after-match JS, when I use `prompt()`, the (alternate) [online version](http://peg.arcanis.fr) throws an error of 'Parse Error: prompt is not defined'. I am trying to use the initializer to create a function to replicate `prompt` (probably not optimized, I was just trying it as a solution). However, when I do this, it still gives me the error. I have tried using `window.prompt` as well, but again, it does not work. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
{
    function cin() {
        window.prompt("");
    }

    function changeVar(variable, newValue) {
        if(typeof variable === typeof newValue) {
            variable = newValue;
        } else if(typeof variable === 'undefined') {
            alert("You can't assign a value to a variable if the variable isn't declared yet!");
        } else {
            alert("Bad assignment. In C++, a variable *must* have the same type *all the time*.");
        }
    }
}

stdin =
    whitespace* "std::cin" whitespace* ">>" whitespace* varToBeChanged:[a-zA-Z_]+ ";" whitespace*
        { changeVar(varToBeChanged, cin('')); return varToBeChanged; }

whitespace =
    space:[ \t]
        { return space; }
```

and then in the parser testing field:

```
std::cin >> variable;
```

Thank you for looking. I have tried Googling this and SO-searching this but I haven't found any results.

Also, here is the [main piece of code](http://peg.arcanis.fr/26gPOh/15/), for all the (current) extra information anyone needs. I am having some problems with this as well, but I'll try to figure them out on my own before I post another question.

Comment: Why do you need to *use* `prompt` for *parsing* the string `cin`? Not sure what you're doing here.

Comment: Someone removed the proper PEG.js formatting. The last line is supposed to be encased in `{}`, making it execute the JS within if `std::cin >> [a-zA-Z_]` is matched. It's not for parsing, it's for actually taking action when the string mentioned above is found. Also, just in case you were confused, `changeVar` is simply a function to change a variable's value without changing its type.

Comment: I've misunderstood how PEG.js is working, apparently it's not only a parser but also an interpreter. I've rollbacked the changes to the syntax.

Comment: Could you please extend the rules to make a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (i.e. add the missing `whitespace` and `changeVar` defs)? Btw, once I've added them to the online version the parser is working well.

Comment: Done. I also added a link to my work so far. It could assist you in trying to solve this as well. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using http://peg.arcanis.fr/, then the parser code is executed inside of a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) - which has no access to any UI like the `window` or the DOM. The error "`undefined variable`" means literally that there is no `window` or `prompt` declared.

If you paste your code into http://pegjs.majda.cz/online, it is executed in the web page environment and works flawlessly.